# Pipeline execution on merge requests in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The master repo has a CI flow that needs to run whenever a merge request is initiated. Currently facing these 2 issues with this flow.

1. A merge request initiated from a user with "DEVELOPER" role doesn't triggers the pipeline, whereas the same merge request from the admin user did trigger the pipeline.
2. The CI configuration used in the pipeline should be of the original repo rather than the CI file from the merge request.

Here is a sample CI configuration

```
tages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - echo "Setting up environment..."

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building..."

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Running tests..."

# This job will be triggered when a merge request is created
merge_request_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Running tests for merge request.."
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to problem 1:

> A merge request initiated from a user with "DEVELOPER" role doesn't
> triggers the pipeline, whereas the same merge request from the admin
> user did trigger the pipeline.

Solution:
a. Check Protected Branches Settings: Ensure that the branch you're
trying to merge into doesn't have protected settings that restrict
pipeline execution to certain roles. Go to your project's Settings >
Repository > Protected Branches and verify the settings there.

b. Review CI/CD Pipeline Settings: In some cases, specific CI/CD
settings might restrict pipeline execution based on roles. Check
Settings > CI/CD and ensure there are no role-based restrictions for
pipeline execution.

> The CI configuration used in the pipeline should be of the original
> repo rather than the CI file from the merge request.

Please note, while this does not directly force the use of the .gitlab-ci.yml from the original repo in running the pipeline, it does ensure that any changes to the CI configuration in merge requests are flagged, requiring manual review and approval. This approach relies on maintaining the integrity of the CI process by preventing unauthorized modifications to the CI configuration.

```html
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - check

before_script:
  - echo "Setting up environment..."

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building..."

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Running tests..."

# This job will be triggered when a merge request is created
merge_request_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Running tests for merge request.."
  only:
    - merge_requests

# Job to check if the .gitlab-ci.yml file has been modified in the merge request
check_ci_file_modification:
  stage: check
  script:
    - 'if git diff --name-only $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME...$CI_COMMIT_SHA | grep -q ".gitlab-ci.yml"; then echo ".gitlab-ci.yml has been modified in the merge request, which is not allowed."; exit 1; fi'
  only:
    - merge_requests
  allow_failure: false
```